# pyautogui mouse scroll PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied

Tags: scroll, permissions, mouse, pyautogui

By running this code

```
import pyautogui
import time

#----------------------------------------------------
def mouse_scroll_1(value= 100):
    pyautogui.vscroll(clicks=value)
    return
#----------------------------------------------------
def mouse_scroll_2(value= 100):
    try:
        pyautogui.vscroll(clicks=value)
    except:
        try:
            pyautogui.vscroll(clicks=value)
        except:
            pass
#----------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input('Focus on a windows (faster then 3 sec) and wait, we will focus down')
    time.sleep(3)
    mouse_scroll_1(-100)
```

I get following error.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    mouse_scroll_1(-100)
  File "test2.py", line 6, in mouse_scroll_1
    pyautogui.vscroll(clicks=value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 582, in vscroll
    platformModule._vscroll(clicks, x, y)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 545, in _vscroll
    return _scroll(clicks, x, y)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 514, in _scroll
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, x, y, dwData=clicks)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied.
```

I could fix the error by running function: mouse_scroll_2()

Can someone please explain what could be the reason of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it with:

```
import win32api
import win32con 

def mouse_scroll_3(value= 100):
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0 , value, 0)
        return
```

Nevertheless no answer why it failed with pyautogui :-(